# Combine big data stored in subdirectories as 100,000+ CSV files of size 200 GB with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, glob

I want to create an algorithm to extract data from csv files in different folders / subfolders. each folder will have 9000 csvs. and we will have 12 of them. 12*9000. over 100,000 files

Comment: Could you please be more precise? Depending on the operations you have to perform on these tables the way to do it can be very different.

Comment: Take a look at this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-memory-management/), maybe it can help you

Comment: @matteo I am not performing analysis on it for now. First I need to get these 9000 csv files from multiple sub directories they are almost 200 gb in size together. I am not sure if methods like glob are efficient in extraction of such large data

Comment: @DonPre storing should not be a problem but extracting process of 9000 files that are almost 200gb will cause ram problems

Comment: @AvneeshChaudhary since you cannot fit 200 GB in memory you have to work on "chunks" and you have to know what kind of task you have to perform. For example, let's assume for sake of simplicity, CSVs have each one the two attributes, "A" and "B" and let's say you want to compute the mean on B. In this case does not matter that you cannot upload all data together since you can read one file at the time and compute the sum, then divide by the number of samples. But for some operation instead, it is necessary to upload "chunks" of a minum size in your memory, and the procedure depends on the task

Comment: For example if you have to compute the union of your CSVs, the case where you don't care about duplicated rows is pretty simple, instead if you have to avoid duplicates you have to work in another way and the algorithm is different, using also some auxiliary data structure for keeping track of what you have already seen. To give you a practial example, consider the case you have to order all the rows on a given attribute, since you can't upload all rows in RAM and run quicksort, you have to use a dedicated procedure called external sorting, here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working solution for over 100,000 files

Credits : Abhishek Thakur - https://twitter.com/abhi1thakur/status/1358794466283388934

```
import pandas as pd
import glob 
import time

    start = time.time()
    
    path = 'csv_test/data/'
    all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
    l = []
    
    for filename in all_files:
      df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header = 0)
      l.append(df)
    
    frame = pd.concat(l, axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
    frame.to_csv('output.csv', index = False)
    
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

not sure if it can handle data of size 200 gb. - need feedback regarding this

Answer (score 1):

If the files have consistent structure (column names and column order), then `dask` can create a large lazy representation of the data:

```py
from dask.dataframe import read_csv

ddf = read_csv('my_path/*/file_*.csv')

# do something
```

Comment: there are around 9000 files in diff sub directories under a master folder

Comment: Yes, dask can handle that.

Answer (score -1):

You can read CSV-files using pandas and store them space efficiently on disk:

```
import pandas as pd
file = "your_file.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file)
data = data.astype({"column1": int})
data.to_hdf("new_filename.hdf", "key")
```

Depending on the contents of your file, you can make adjustments to read_csv as described here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
Make sure that after you've read your data in as a dataframe, the column types match the types they are holding. This way you can save a lot of storage in memory and later when saving these dataframes to disk. You can use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to make these adjustments.
After you've done that, store your dataframe to disk with [to_hdf](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html).
If your data is compatible across csv-files, you can [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) the dataframes onto each other into a larger dataframe.

Comment: I don’t have a single file, I have 9000 files to extracted almost 200 gb in size total. My problem is during extraction of such large data I may face ram issues